# Flutter create custom search UI extends SearchDelegate

Tags: flutter

I have a fully tested Search class which extends **SearchDelegate**, it always shows the `Searchbar` within the `appbar` as *material design*.

[image: main Search delegate UI]

**But I want it to be like this one below**

[image]

**How can I change the UI of the `Searchbar`? without leaving the `SearchDelegate` methods like**

-buildActions

-buildLeading

-buildResults ... etc

Comment: If the built in widget does not suit your use case, simply modify it and add your functionality yourself. The entire source is available on flutter repo.

Comment: @Darish can I do something like extend and override?

Comment: try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead it is a widget for Flutter, where you can show suggestions to users as they type - its easy to use and provides high customization options

Comment: @Darish any other options?

Answer (score 0):

[showSearch](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showSearch.html) function is always displayed on the AppBar. You can use [CupertinoSearchTextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSearchTextField-class.html) widget from the cupertino library to have an iOS-oriented search TextField similar to the screenshot you've shared. Another workaround for the feature that you're looking for is by using [AutoComplete](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html) Widget